# Updating Redux Store from GraphQL Query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

What I'm trying to do is Query for the Current User during an Auth phase, take what is returned, and then render the application layout.

Flow:

`<App />` => `<Auth />` (Query Current User) => `{current_user}` => `setAuthUser(current_user)` Action => `<Layout />`.

I would like to have this User available throughout the application via connecting to the store.

The problem is I'm stuck in an infinite loop with trying to setState while a component is rendering and not sure how I can do this another way.

**Auth.jsx**

```
...import statements...

class Auth extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }
  // Tried using the shouldComponentUpdate lifecycle but running into the same issues
  shouldComponentUpdate() {
     if (loading) { return true; } 
     this.props.SET_AUTH_USER(this.props.data.current_user); <<<<<< Creates loop
  }
  render() {
    const { loading, error, current_user } = this.props.data;
    if (loading) { /* handle loading */ }
    if (error) { /* handle error */ }

    if (current_user) {
      //this.props.SET_AUTH_USER(); <<<<<<< This again creates the loop
      <Layout />;
    }
    return ;
  }
}

export default compose(graphql(fetchCurrentUser),connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps))(Auth);
```

I originally tried this as a functional component, and with the error thought maybe using a LifeCycle Method like `shouldComponentUpdate` and everything I've tried just leads me to setting state while rendering a component which wont work.

A lot of examples I've been seeing discuss this with a user action and using `bind`. But I'd like to have this done in a synchronous method. Is there a way to get this to run?

The other options I thought of could be running the current user query when needed or setting a cookie. Ideally would like to have this in the Redux Store.

Comment: I fell in the same trap initially. I found one work around, though it might not be the best one. I did all authentication in the parent component and sent the current_user as props to all child components. where it was validated and used.

Comment: I was considering that or just having the child `<Layout />` do the dispatch in a `componentDidMount` method. I'm reading something about `mapQueriesToProps` but documentation isn't making much sense to me in how to implement it in this case.

Comment: So looks like there's a way with using Recompose helper library. 
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/recipes/recompose.html#query-lifecycle

I tried implementing it and the Apollo docs were too hard to follow for me. I don't have too much time to fuse with it but for future reference that's probably the preferred method.